# I want to restart nodemon server programmatically every 20 minutes

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, nodemon

I want to restart nodemon server app.js programmatically every 20 minutes with restart.js.

I'm starting with nodemon -r esm app.js . and server.js should relaunch it somehow.

I tried with pm2 and forever various combinations I don't even remember since none of them worked.

Comment: Ok. But why? Where are you hosting and what are you trying to solve?

Comment: They are hosted at the same localhost. There are too many requests from various servers and so far best solution is to just restart

Comment: Nodemon is basically a tool that one uses to restart when the code changes. If it's crashing that's not a good sign, something like pm2 can keep the server up, but it smells like there's another issue here

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forever-monitor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever-monitor) and `setInterval` to terminate the child and create a new one each X time you want.

Comment: Accoding to the linked page, "*By default, nodemon waits for one second to restart the process when a file changes, but with the `--delay` switch, you can specify a different delay.*". This is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Since it's completely different, I would've kept the old one deleted and just posted a separate, second answer. Anyway, removed my downvote :-)

Comment: I can't post 2 answers in 1 question :)

Comment: Yes, you can! For cases such as this, there's [an "*Add another answer*" button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255359/1048572) at the bottom. I don't think it has a reputation threshold.